# Cross-platform Google OAuth Signin: redirect_uri mismatch

Tags: php, android, oauth, google-oauth, google-signin

I use Google OAuth for authenticating users on my application and face an issue with `redirect_uri` to support multiple client apps.

On the server-side, I provide a REST API which uses the Google PHP SDK, the login flow is almost similar to what's described here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

I have two client apps: a website using the JavaScript SDK and an Android app using the android client, implemented as https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

I have no redirect_uri's configured in Google console. My issue is that I set the `redirect_uri` to `postmessage` in my server code, but I'm unable to get this working with the Android app: I get a `redirect_uri mismatch` error.

```
$this->client = new Google_Client;
$this->client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');
```

Without this uri, google login on my web client throws an error `Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message:

> invalid_request: Missing parameter: redirect_uri

If I do not specify a redirect_uri, login works fine on Android, but the web-client doesn't work. How do I workaround this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the redirect uri as following:

1. If it's web sdk set it to `'postmessage'`
2. If it's mobile (android in your case) set it to `''` (empty string)

Pass from the client some kind of identifier so you will know in the server which redirect uri you should set.

Comment: Thank you SOOOOOO much for this! Out of curiosity, do you know where this is this explained in the docs?

Comment: So frustrating. But at least it helps my sanity to know I didn't simply miss something. Again, thank you SOOOOO much!