# How to set up iOS Google Sign In with backend integration?

Tags: ios, go, cross-platform, google-oauth

I'm trying to follow the instructions at: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access. Whenever I send a token I get: "redirect_uri_mismatch".

I read in another question that client ids need to wait for a bit. This is not the case. The backend id has been active since August. The web app works fine. The server json sets "redirect_uris" to "postmessage".

This looks very similar to the question: [Cross-platform Google OAuth Signin: redirect_uri mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877951/cross-platform-google-oauth-signin-redirect-uri-mismatch) but my scenario is with iOS and Go.

If I add a scope "audience:server:client_id:" as suggested by https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth I get an "invalid scope" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way.

First, forget about "audience:server:client_id:".

```
    let signin = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
    signin.clientID = "XXXX-YYYY.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    signin.serverClientID = "XXXX-ZZZZ.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    signin.scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")
    signin.delegate = self
```

Second, redirect_uris don't matter.

Last, the only thing else that you need to be careful is that `serverAuthCode` will only come once. So be sure to `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut` if you support log out.