# How to debug server-side `redirect_uri_mismatch` error from Google Signin

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-signin, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm attempting to use Google Sign-In with a firebase function following Google's documentation for [Google Sign-In for server-side apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow), however I'm running into a `redirect_uri_mismatch` error (unlike the examples in that documentation, I am using [Google's nodejs SDK](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)).

The general flow I'm following is to use google's javascript SDK to request an `offlineAccessCode()` from a user, send that access code to the server (firebase function), use the access code to get an access token and refresh token, and save the refresh token for later use (this is the flow outlined in the documentation).

It might seem like the meaning of the term `redirect_uri_mismatch` is self-explanatory, but, as stated in the linked documentation, `The Authorized redirect URI field does not require a value. Redirect URIs are not used with JavaScript APIs.` That line comes from the section *"Step 1: Create a client ID and client secret"* and is explaining how to configure the OAuth client credentials. This is the only time in the documentation that a redirect uri is mentioned, and there is no indication that a redirect URI is needed when the server uses the authorization code to fetch an access token.

Indeed, the concept of a redirect uri doesn't seem to make sense in the context of a cloud function using an access code obtained from a client. If the server needs to supply a matching `redirect_uri` as the javascript client (which doesn't seem to be specified anywhere), I'm not sure what `redirect_uri` the javascript client uses.

So with that background, does anyone have any idea how to solve this `redirect_uri_mismatch` error?

Or, more generally, any pointers on implementing this auth flow (my cloud function is written in javascript using the [google nodejs sdk](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)). I'm finding it very hard to debug this issue.

## Update

I realized that the reason why the error message says `redirect_uri_mismatch` is because I had been testing various values as `redirect_uri`. When I remove the (optional) `redirect_uri` param from the request, the response from google's servers is `invalid_request: Missing parameter redirect_uri`. So google's making it clear that it *wants* a redirect URI, even as the documentation seems to imply that it isn't necessary for this auth flow. As a larger problem, the documentation doesn't seem to describe how to set up a redirect URI for an auth flow on a single page app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah HA! The answer (as given in [this other S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55221307/5490505)) is to set the `redirect_uri` to `"postmessage"` on the server (firebase function in my case). I have no idea where this answer came from (i.e. I haven't been able to find it in the docs), but it works.